# Why does `(console.error = console.trace)();` make `heap out of memory` in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js v5.8.0.

I wanted to make `console.error` work as `console.trace`, so I used `console.error = console.trace;`. But when I called the `console.error`, a fatal memory error occurred:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   29296 ms: Mark-sweep 1328.1 (1403.1) -> 1328.1 (1404.1) MB, 32.8 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
   29314 ms: Mark-sweep 1328.1 (1404.1) -> 1328.1 (1404.1) MB, 17.8 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
   29333 ms: Mark-sweep 1328.1 (1404.1) -> 1338.8 (1403.1) MB, 19.7 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
   29353 ms: Mark-sweep 1338.8 (1403.1) -> 1349.7 (1403.1) MB, 19.3 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000318EFDCFB61 <JS Object>
    1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:~129] [pc=00000130FFFB1B73] (this=00000318EFD04381 <undefined>,w=000001FBBADF90E1 <JS Array[17]>,x=17,N=00000318EFD043C1 <true>,J=000003D7BECEC771 <String[1]\: \n>,I=00000318EFDB46F1 <JS Function ConvertToString (SharedFunctionInfo 00000318EFD52DC9)>)
    2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:180] [pc=00000130FFF08772] (this=00000318EFD04381 <undefined>...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

What's the reason? Does `console.trace` call `console.error` internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NodeJS, `console.error` and `console.warn` are used to print to the standard error output. `console.trace` uses `console.error` internally to print to the standard error output as `console.trace` is often used for errors.

Here is a link to the line where  `console.trace` calls `console.error`:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1c84579031e34326742c9c264f54625c5918197c/lib/console.js#L89

You can try this code:

```
console.trace = function trace() {
  var err = new Error();
  err.name = 'Trace';
  err.message = util.format.apply(null, arguments);
  Error.captureStackTrace(err, trace);
  this.oldWarn(err.stack);
};

console.oldWarn = console.warn;
console.error = console.warn = console.trace;
```